# EDB schema dump with pg_dump - server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, mismatch, edb

I'd like to create a dump from an EDB 14 server schema. I installed postgresql 14 server locally.
When I try to create the dump from pgAdmin I got this error:

```
pg_dump: error: server version: 14.7.0; pg_dump version: 14.7
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

What is the problem?

**SOLUTION:**

The `pg_dump` included with open source `PostgreSQL 14.7` throws an error when run against an `EDB Advanced Server`, even if they have the same version number. Therefore, it is necessary to download the specific version of `EDB Advanced Server` from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/software-downloads-postgres) and use the pg_dump module that comes with it.

Comment: I assume that "EDB 14" is a fork of PostgreSQL, right? Then use `pg_dump` from the same fork.

Comment: EDB means enterprise db, a paid version of postgresql. And I downloaded PostgresSQL 14 from edb.com. So there is no other postgres 14 version as far as I know.

Comment: No, sorry, that is unclear. Did you download open source PostgreSQL or EDB's proprietary fork?

Comment: I downloaded windows 14.7 version from here: [link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

Comment: then you should ask their support

Comment: No open source version of PostgreSQL has version number 14.7.0. Could you connect to the server, run `SELECT version();`, edit the question and add the result?

Comment: You were right Laurenz Albe. I downloaded the `EDB Postgres Advanced Server v14.7` from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/software-downloads-postgres) and it includes the right version of pg_dump. I can dump the scheme from the server now with it. Thank you for the help!